# Can't login to directus using route that is written in docs

Tags: directus

I'm using Keycloak as provider to login in directus. I can enter Directus web interface using keycloak. But there is a route in Directus docs (https://docs.directus.io/reference/authentication.html#login) for login using provider using API.

I get an error:

```json
{
    "message": "Route /auth/login/keycloak doesn't exist.",
    "extensions": {
        "code": "ROUTE_NOT_FOUND"
    }
}
```

What is the right route to login in Directus using providers (keycloak etc.)